# Gridview not sorting properly on DateTime coloumn

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

```
Private Sub GridViewLog_StartSorting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles GridViewLog.StartSorting
SetDefaultSort()
End Sub

Private Sub SetDefaultSort()
        Dim col1 As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn
        Dim col2 As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn
        Dim sortIndex As Integer
        Dim order As DevExpress.Data.ColumnSortOrder
        Try
            col1 = GridViewLog.Columns("Date_Field")
            col2 = GridViewLog.Columns("Time_Field")
            If Not ((GridViewLog.SortedColumns.Contains(col1) OrElse GridViewLog.GroupedColumns.Contains(col1)) AndAlso (GridViewLog.SortedColumns.Contains(col2) OrElse GridViewLog.GroupedColumns.Contains(col2))) Then

                Me.GridViewLog.BeginSort()

                If col1.SortOrder = DevExpress.Data.ColumnSortOrder.None Then
                    order = col2.SortOrder
                Else
                    order = col1.SortOrder
                End If
                If order = DevExpress.Data.ColumnSortOrder.None Then
                    order = DevExpress.Data.ColumnSortOrder.Descending
                End If
                sortIndex = GridViewLog.SortedColumns.Count
                Me.GridViewLog.Columns("Date_Field").SortIndex = sortIndex - 1
                Me.GridViewLog.Columns("Date_Field").SortOrder = order
                Me.GridViewLog.Columns("Time_Field").SortIndex = sortIndex
                Me.GridViewLog.Columns("Time_Field").SortOrder = order
                Me.GridViewLog.EndSort()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
     End Sub
```

Changed some times to 10:31 and they didn't re-sort. I then hit Time at the top of the column and it still didn’t change. Please check the attached screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two options:

1. Set the columns' `SortMode` property to `ColumnSortMode.Value`
2. Use `CustomColumnSort` event and set the columns' `SortMode` property to `ColumnSortMode.Custom`

Comment: i have test by setting ColumnSortMode.Value =ColumnSortMode.Value still the coloumn not sorts properly